# Add to hashmap in sorted fashion (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, optimization, hashmap, treemap

Hashmaps take O(1) to get stuff or remove it. If I want to sort it it will take nlogn time with Collections.sort(). If I use a treemap instead it sorts them while adding them so I don't have to spend nlogn sorting but it takes nlogn finding stuff. Hence the question is can I manually control the hashmap put method so that it doesn't use the hashcode way but instead sorts them with comparable? I am seeking O(1) for a program that uses hashmaps to do many insertions and removals and also much sorting.

Comment: `TreeMap` is O(log n) for retrieval, not O(n log n).

Comment: But to answer your question: you can't.  You can't have (expected) O(1) for everything, and *also* have a sorted dataset.

Comment: What's the problem with a `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting `n` items will (in almost every case) take `O(n log n)` time. This is a provable fact. See [Wikipedia on Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for a lot of information on the bounds on sorting algorithms.